# I want to know how insert the values in the table when we dont know about the fields that we are entering

Tags: mysql, for-loop

I have a text field

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

I want to enter a integer in this text field and want to open other text field(s) equal to number enter in that text field.

eg. I enter 4 number in the $number then the 4 text fields will open.

the code I used for this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
  extract($_POST);
  for($i=1;$i<=$number;i++)
  {
     <input type="text" name="">
     //insert mysql query to insert into table
  }
}
?>
```

but i don't know how to insert these values in the table.

Comment: if you trying the use query in loop it wont be a good idea its make your site really very slow even if there are many input type than you even see slow speed on localserver

Comment: what do you want to insert in to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
   extract($_POST);
   for($i=1;$i<=$number;i++)
   {
      <input type="text" name="text[]">
     //insert mysql query to insert into table
   }
   //Here you insert the text field values with name "text" which is an array.You can implode them with ',' and insert into your database
 }
?>
```

Comment: @Ravneet 'Abid':    sql example

Comment: insert into my_table('my_text')values($_POST['text'])

Answer (score 0):

```
try with this code
//HTML CODE 
<input type="text" name="range" id="range" />
<input type="button" onclick="insertInputBox()" value="Insert TextBox" />
<div id="inputHolder">
</div> 

//JAVASCRIPT
function insertInputBox()
{
    var rangeLimit=document.getElementById('range').value;
    var i=1;
    for(i=1;i<=rangeLimit;i++)
    {
       document.getElementById('inputHolder').innerHTML+='<input type="text" name=i+"range" id=i+"range" /><br />';
    }
}
```